# Underscore js - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I use the mustache interpolation:

```
    _.templateSettings = {
        interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
    };
```

and for this code I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

```
<div class="d-none flex-container tip-container bg-white mt-5" data-ajax-template-empty-tip>

        <div class="tip-header border border-bottom-0 d-flex flex-row p-2">

            <div class="align-self-center mr-2">
                <a href="./{{countryName}}" target="_blank">
                    <img class="d-block" alt="" src="/images/flags/{{countryId}}.png">
                </a>
            </div>


            {{if (typeof(cityName) !== "undefined") { }}
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left align-self-center mr-2"></i>
            <div class="align-self-center mr-2">
                <a class="badge badge-primary" role="button" href="/city/{{cityName}}" target="_blank">
                    <span>{{cityName}}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            {{}}}

        </div>

    </div>
```

Without the if statement it works well, but with it won't work, any idea what's wrong? I looked in every question online and couldn't figure it out, I even removed the interpolation and used the default <% but it wouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

Try a space before the if, like this :

```
{{ if (typeof(cityName) !== "undefined") { }}
```

Comment: I think it's because of the `_.templateSettings` do you have the right settings for {{ }} syntax?

Comment: Tried it with regex101.com, it seems fine. Did you try the spac before `if` ?